# Data value in the wpf grid is not getting right and center aligned

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, wpfdatagrid

I am using wpf data grid . I want data to be right and center aligned in the grid .Currently I am using Style setter property but nothing is working for me

```
private void DgvInvoice_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
        {

                    DataGridColumn nextColumn = DgvInvoice.ColumnFromDisplayIndex(7); // Display Index 7 is Amount Colum in the grid 

                    DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)DgvInvoice.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(new DataGridCellInfo(DgvInvoice.SelectedItem, nextColumn).Item);

                    DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(row);

                    DataGridCell gridCell = presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(7) as DataGridCell;
                    if (gridCell != null)
                    {

                        if (d != 0)
                        {
                            gridCell.Content = String.Format("{0:#,0}", d);
                        }
                        else { gridCell.Content = string.Empty; }

                        Style s = new Style();
                        gridCell.Height = 29;
                        s.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBox.TextAlignmentProperty, TextAlignment.Right));
                        s.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBox.VerticalContentAlignmentProperty, VerticalAlignment.Center));
                        gridCell.Style = s;
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
Style alignStyle = new Style(typeof(DataGridCell));
alignStyle.Setters.Add(new  Setter(DataGridCell.WidthProperty, 20.0));
alignStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridCell.HorizontalAlignmentProperty,HorizontalAlignment.Center));
alignStyle.Setters.Add(new  Setter(DataGridCell.VerticalAlignmentProperty,VerticalAlignment.Center));
YouDataGridName.Style = alignStyle;
```

Answer (score 0):

i just have xaml style for you

```
    <Style x:Key="GridCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Right" />
    </Style>

 <DataGridTextColumn Header="Betrag" MinWidth="125"
                Binding="{Binding Path=Betrag, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat=#\,##0.00}"
                ElementStyle="{StaticResource GridCellStyle}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: the title here asks for "Grid" which is different than "DataGrid".